# The correct decision of storing objects in memory (composite pattern)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management

I have already object of CCompositePrimitive class in Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    ...
    CCompositePrimitive DrawObjects;
    ...
}
```

The CCompositePrimitive class has field:

```
private:
 list<CDrawObject*> m_Objects;
```

and method:

```
public:
 Add(...);


void CCompositePrimitive::Add() {
 Objects.push_back(new Rectangle(...))
}
```

On some forums ask me that `DrawObjects` object will be stored in heap. But I think else. In my opinion `DrawObjects` object will be stored in stack.
How I can preserve computer's memory of stack overflow (any different memory problems), if DrawObjects can store in list m_Objects; very many objects, which can content CCompositePrimitive objects too (composite pattern).

Comment: you will probably save yourself a lot of processing time and memory by using std::vector instead of list

Comment: why if i will be using std::vector instead of list i do save memory management?

Comment: Depends if he wants to insert and remove items from the middle or shuffle them around.

Comment: Some methods is using insert and erase function of STL, for moving objects

Comment: because vector doesn't require storing additional pointers for elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the class where `CCompositePrimitive m_DrawOjects;` is stored in gets created. (I assume it's stored inside a class because of the `m_`)
If your class is created on the stack, then `m_DrawObjects` will be too. If your class is created on the heap, so will be `m_DrawObjects`.
But indifferent of wether `m_DrawObjects` is created on the heap or the stack, the objects inside the `list<CDrawObject*> m_Objects;` will be created on the heap, because that's how a linked list works.

**Edit**: According to your edit and comment, then `DrawObjects` is of course created on the stack. :) But what I said about the objects inside the list still holds true.

Comment: Oh... I did mistake. CCompositePrimitive DrawOjects;. "CCompositePrimitive DrawOjects;" is define in main() function.

Comment: May be define CCompositePrimitive *DrawOjects; and allocate memory for DrawOjects = new CCompositePrimitive(); ? or it hasn't to be done

Comment: @G-71: If you do it like that, then of course DrawObjects will be on the heap.

Comment: it is neccecary to me that when there are many created objects don't be stack overflow.

Comment: @G-71: If you need the objects dynamically or beyond the scope of your function, then you must use the heap. If you only need them, say, in your `main` function, you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Items you put into any STL collection are dynamically allocated. Your main issue is managing the lifetime of the pointers in the collection.

vector will store the pointers in contiguous storage and will therefore use less overhead per item as it does not need pointers to next and previous nodes.

list is more efficient in time when you are inserting or removing other than at the end of the collection, and will never have an overhead of reallocating when you grow beyond capacity.

deque is the best collection to use if you never want the overhead of reallocating, have large numbers of objects that do not need contiguous storage, and are only inserting and removing from the ends: either end - but never in the middle.

If you want to manage the lifetime of the pointers themselves you could use shared_ptr as your collection type. There is an overhead in that too. boost provides typesafe pointer-collections that manage the memory of the items in them.

Comment: Thank you very much. But my main issue is where m_DrawOjects object is stored: in stack (that is emmited overflow) or in heap. I'm begginer c++ developer and make stupid question

Comment: To be created on the heap, you have to call the new operator. Like CashCow says, you will create your object on the heap, creating them using `new`. ie when you write `new Rectangle(...)` this creates the rectangle on the heap.

Comment: If it is a class member it will be created with the instance of the class. Even though its destruction may be "automatic", if the memory of the class is on the heap (or "free storage"), so will be any members it has.